# need to remove some space in css

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I need to remove the space between the middle player and the bottom border

I tried to make the left and right border shorter but id doesn't work it, as I expected

i'm trying to make a box that contain the player but with head and shoulders out

```css
.top-captains {
  background-color: blueviolet;
  border: black;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px 1px 1px 1px;
  height: 25rem;
  margin-top: 10rem;
  margin-bottom: -10rem;
}

.top-captains .firstPlayer {
  border-color: black;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 20px;
  max-height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
}

div img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10rem;
  object-fit: contain;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


   <section class="top-section ">
      <div class="top-captains row">
        <div class="thirdPlayer col">
          <img src="https://one-versus-one.com/img/players/jamie-vardy-72644-ub-800.png" alt="#" />
        </div>

        <div class="firstPlayer col">
          <img
            src="https://one-versus-one.com/img/players/kevin-de-bruyne-13310-ub-800.png"
            alt="#"
          />
        </div>

        <div class="secPlayer col">
          <img
            src="https://one-versus-one.com/img/players/marcus-rashford-201718-ub-800.png"
            alt="#"
          />
        </div>
      </div>

    </section>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reduce the height of the main wrapper, increase the one of the image and use `bottom:0`. Don't forget `container` since you are using `row`

```css
.top-captains {
  background-color: blueviolet;
  border: black;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px 1px 1px 1px;
  height: 12rem; /* updated */
  margin-top: 10rem;
  margin-bottom: -10rem;
}

.top-captains .firstPlayer {
  border-color: black;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 20px;
  max-height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
}

div img {
  left:0;
  right:0;
  width:100%;
  height: 150%; /*updated*/
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0; /*updated*/
  object-fit: contain;
  object-position: bottom; /* Needed for small screen*/
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


   <section class="top-section container-fluid">
      <div class="top-captains row">
        <div class="thirdPlayer col">
          <img src="https://one-versus-one.com/img/players/jamie-vardy-72644-ub-800.png" alt="#" />
        </div>

        <div class="firstPlayer col">
          <img
            src="https://one-versus-one.com/img/players/kevin-de-bruyne-13310-ub-800.png"
            alt="#"
          />
        </div>

        <div class="secPlayer col">
          <img
            src="https://one-versus-one.com/img/players/marcus-rashford-201718-ub-800.png"
            alt="#"
          />
        </div>
      </div>

    </section>
```

Comment: is there a way to keep the original size of the player?

Comment: @KhaledMahmoud keep increasing the height of the image until you get what you want (or decrease it)

Answer (score 0):

I guess you also need to set `z-index` to make it as you wish.

```css
.top-captains {
  background-color: blueviolet;
  border: black;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px 1px 1px 1px;
  height: 25rem;
  margin-top: 10rem;
  margin-bottom: -10rem;
}

.top-captains .firstPlayer {
  border-color: black;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 20px;
  max-height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
}

div img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10rem;
  object-fit: contain;
  z-index: 101;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


   <section class="top-section ">
      <div class="top-captains row">
        <div class="thirdPlayer col">
          <img src="https://one-versus-one.com/img/players/jamie-vardy-72644-ub-800.png" alt="#" />
        </div>

        <div class="firstPlayer col">
          <img
            src="https://one-versus-one.com/img/players/kevin-de-bruyne-13310-ub-800.png"
            alt="#"
          />
        </div>

        <div class="secPlayer col">
          <img
            src="https://one-versus-one.com/img/players/marcus-rashford-201718-ub-800.png"
            alt="#"
          />
        </div>
      </div>

    </section>
```

Please up-vote if it was helpful :)

Comment: it still the same